# Read numbers to vector

Tags: c++, input, vector

I'm struggling hard with this. Basically, I have to read a number first:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Then I have to read N intervals to a vector:

```
vector< vector<int> > intervals;
int a, b;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
  intervals.at(i).at(0) = a;
  intervals.at(i).at(1) = b;
}
```

Using GDB debugger, I get this:

```
3
1 4
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7260c35 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
intervals.at(i).at(0) = a;
```

Is illegal, since your vector is initially empty. You can either use `push_back` or pre-allocate the vector.

I would pre-allocate the vector, since this would require no further re-allocation on `push_back`:

```
vector< vector<int> > intervals(n);
int a, b;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
  intervals.at(i).push_back(a);
  intervals.at(i).push_back(b);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `at` to store to elements of the vector that don't exist yet.

The easiest fix is to use `push_back` to put new elements into the vector - that's what it was designed to do. You'll need to use it twice since you have two dimensions.